# Microsoft Exchange: Add appointment to another's calendar

Tags: outlook, vsto, exchange-server

I'm trying to develop a custom solution that involves Exchange and Outlook (via a VSTO plugin).

In an Exchange connected Outlook is it possible that from an account to add appointments for another account?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

via delegation it should be possible. As long as you have permission on the other mailbox (need to change exchange permission).

Another way would be to just send an appointment to the second mailbox and it will be visible in the second calendar (if not deleted/rejected by the user)